# Set text in image on iOs' browser

Tags: javascript, ios

iOS' browser only allows JavaScript FileReader to read images. Renaming images to `.txt` will make them fail the check, so I guess some validation exists.
Is there a way to bypass it?

```
$("#fileinput").change(function(evt){
  var r = new FileReader();
  r.onload = function(evt){   //file loaded successfuly
       contents = evt.target.result;
    ...
  }
  r.readAsText(f);
});
```

Comment: Do you want to be able to upload textfiles or manipulate the images somehow?

Comment: hi Piw, i want to upload txt by Safari, etc, but only image is allowed by the browser.

Comment: That might be because iOS's filesystem is basically protected / restricted from the outside with the exception of images. I mean if you could search for text files on your device in the first place when trying to upload one - you would have a working file browser on iOS, which is not possible.